# What is the fastest way to play sound after pressing a button on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know much about Flutter. I don't know how to play a sound the fastest. The fastest method I've tried has a delay of 250 milliseconds. All I want to do is have a button make a sound. I guess what I need to do is to cache the audio, but I don't have enough information for that. I'll be happy if you can help me.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more detail on the matter? I.e. snippet of code that you have, or the package you're using?

Comment: I used packages in the methods I tried. I had the best results with the "just_audio" package. I tried "audioplayers", "flutter_sound" and even "flutter_midi". There is a quarter-second delay after pressing the button. I also tried with apk on my phone, the result did not change. I don't know if I should use a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what to do with help from mortiz's answer:

pubspec.yaml, import required class:

```
dependencies:
      audioplayers: ^0.20.1 # Not "1.0.1". Because audioplayers/audio_cache.dart does not exist.
```

import required class:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
```

add an asset in the same file and place the file with sound to assets folder (if you don't have this folder, create it)

```
assets:
- assets/sound_alarm.mp3
```

then add this code:

```
static AudioCache player = new AudioCache();
const alarmAudioPath = "sound_alarm.mp3";
```

To cache the audio we need to overwrite this in the initstate method:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    player.load(alarmAudioPath );
  }
```

Then we can play the sound with this function:

```
player.play(alarmAudioPath );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for playing a file already defined in assets is using AudioCache. Library: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayers. More about AudioCache After adding library to pubspec.yaml, import required class:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
```

add an asset in the same file and place the file with sound to assets folder (if you don't have this folder, create it)

```
assets:
- assets/sound_alarm.mp3
```

then add this code:

```
static AudioCache player = new AudioCache();
const alarmAudioPath = "sound_alarm.mp3";
player.play(alarmAudioPath);
```

Comment: I have tried this before. Maybe there was a change in the package Because I am getting an error like this:  The method 'play' isn't defined for the type 'AudioCache'.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player this package.

FlutterRingtonePlayer.play(fromAsset: "assets/ringtone.mp3",);
and when you want to stop sound just stop using

FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();